# Find the domain of $f(x, y) = \sqrt{1-x^2} - \sqrt{25-y^2}$

Tags: calculus

Sorry in advance for posting this simple question. This is kinda important and I just need to quickly double-check on this.

**Question:** Find the domain of the following function: $$f(x, y) = \sqrt{1-x^2} - \sqrt{25-y^2}$$

**My attempt:** I was able to graph the function out with GeoGebra but I couldn't exactly figure out if the domain is $[-1, 1]$ or $(1, 1)$. From the looks of the function, there is no restriction for the domain at $x =-1$ and $1$ so I'd assume that the domain is $[-1, 1]$. Is there a mathematical way of solving this and proving what the domain is?

Comment: In fact, the domain is $[-1,1] \times [-5,5]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a simple algebraic way to analyze this. Unless you want complex numbers, $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ is only valid as long as $1 - x^2 \geq 0$ or $x^2 \leq 1$ or $|x| \leq \sqrt{1} = 1$. In other words you need $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

Similarly $\sqrt{25 - y^2}$ is only valid as long as $25 - y^2 \geq 0$ or $y^2 \leq 25$ or $|y| \leq \sqrt{25} = 5$. In other words you need $-5 \leq y \leq 5$.

Thus, the domain is $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -1 \leq x \leq 1, -5 \leq y \leq 5\}$ which is just $[-1, 1] \times [-5, 5]$.